# iPhone running slow, overheating, draining fast

Tags: iphone, battery

For a few months, my iPhone 8 has been acting strange

It's been freezing, lagging, and responding slow. About once a day, the phone becomes really slow, to the point of being unusable. This lasts about thirty seconds. During this time, the phone heats up quite a bit, and the battery drains a lot faster than normal. It often happens while opening the app menu (double click home button) or after exiting Safari.

In addition to this problem, my phone's battery drains really fast when using certain apps. When browsing Safari, my phone can lose 5-10% in a minute.

Another example of this is when recording video. The phone's battery drains ridiculously fast (just like above) and the phone often gets hot to the point where the flash becomes unavailable.

A final example is the DJI Fly app. When flying my drone and connected to the controller, I get at most 30-45 minutes of time before my phone drops from 100% to 10%. The phone also heats up quite a bit during this time.

I checked the battery health - it still has plenty left, 67%.

Safari has no tabs open.

Attempted troubleshooting:

- Turned off Bluetooth and WiFi - No effect
- Turned on Low Power Mode - No effect, battery sometimes drains *faster*
- Turned down screen brightness - Slight effect, not much
- Turned off Location - The battery lasts about twice as long while using the phone normally, but does not affect the rapid overheat/drain while using certain apps.
- Restarted the phone - The phone dropped 15% *while restarting*, no effect afterward
- Charging the phone - The phone doesn't heat up as much, and the battery lasts longer. Some apps still drain the battery faster than it can charge, and the percentage goes down anyway.

Comment: In reality, a battery down at 67% life is dead & in need of replacement. My last phone, a 6S, went through two batteries in 6 years, each down to >70% life by the time I changed it out. In real-world terms that meant leaving it on low power mode most of the time & never being more then 4 hours away from a charger. https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLXQQ.png

Answer (score 1):

I have seen phones that need a restore on occasion. I would do that and when you sign in - do not restore any backup. I also would not install any third party apps, sign in to any cloud accounts and just use Safari for an hour to see if you feel it’s substantially better with a clean restore.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204184

Erase all contents is not sufficient - you will want to connect to a computer and restore it. Again, make sure you get a good backup or two, just don’t restore them initially while you test the hardware.

Comment: Why erasing all contents (as if you're parting with it) is not sufficient?

Comment: That doesn’t reinstall the OS or erase the file system. It’s a “light clean” and can solve this, just not as likely the “fix” needed.